# Phonegap, Mysql, ajax // No Insert

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i try to insert from html to mysql (Phonegap). But he don´t make that... What is my mistake?. Sry for my bad englisch and thx for helping...
I have 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
HTML:

```
    <div id="landmark-1" data-landmark-id="1">
        <form>

    <div id="block1">Datum:<input type="date" id="date" name="date"></div>
    <div id="block2">Baustelle:  <input name="bau" id="bau" class="tb1" type="text" size="18" /></div>
<div id="block4">
<input type="submit" value="Speichern">
</div>

    </form>
    </div>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Post.js

```
$(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(){
            var landmarkID = $(this).parent().attr('data-landmark-id');
            var postData = $(this).serialize();
            alert(postData+'&lid='+landmarkID);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: postData+'&lid='+landmarkID,

                //change the url for your project
                url: "http://voss-hm.de/zeitserver/save.php",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('Your comment was successfully added');
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('There was an error adding your comment');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
PHP:

```
<?php
$server = "--------------";
$username = "--------------";
$password = "--------------";
$database = "--------------";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$id = $_Post["id"];
$date = ($_Post["date"]);
$baustelle = ($_Post["bau"]);



$sql = "INSERT INTO timesave.$id (datum, baustelle, anfang, ende, pause) VALUES ('$date' , '$baustelle', '', '', '')";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Comment added";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: `<form>` without required attributes. Spellchecks, Syntax, _deprecated_ mysql functions. `if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {` Looks like a trap. _must. not. fall._

Comment: I wouldn't use mysql_* API, and as u_mulder said: Change your $_Post for $_POST, and also remove parentesis (just in case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes here.

First, use $_POST instead of $_Post (case matters).

Second, you should not use mysql_* function anymore. Please read this tutorial : https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17

Your script is vulnerable to a lot of attacks right now, you really need to learn to escape POST values. Your script will also not work if you have single quote in your posted values. The link below will teach you how to handle this.

Returning JSON-encoded objects from your PHP script would also be a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, the £ sign was a typping mistake. Short version : replace $_Post by $_POST. But the poster really need to read the link provided.

Comment: However these were the mistakes OP had made but this is still not the answer to the question posted above.

Comment: How do you know the issue is not related to the $_POST mistake ?
And without proper escaping of quotes, the script can also fail to work, depending of which values are sent.

Answer (score 0):

1. Its `$_POST` not `$_Post`
2. Please do not use `mysql_`-functions! Use `mysqli_`or PDO instead.

Comment: The issue is not related to the "acction" attribute as the post is handled by AJAX.

Comment: You're right. Edited it

Comment: However these were the mistakes OP had made but this is still not the answer to the question posted above.